# How can I install TrueCrypt on Ubuntu 14?

Tags: 14.04, console, truecrypt

Are their any safe sources to download from?

Comment: The one in the software center is not good enough?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-truecrypt-cli-on-linux. The information in the site may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Might be able to use cryptsetup. See `man cryptsetup`:

```
TCRYPT (TrueCrypt-compatible) EXTENSION
   cryptsetup  supports mapping of TrueCrypt or tcplay encrypted partition
   using a native Linux kernel API.  Header formatting and  TCRYPT  header
   change  is  not  supported,  cryptsetup never changes TCRYPT header on-
   device.

...

   open --type tcrypt <device> <name>
   tcryptOpen <device> <name>  (old syntax)

          Opens the TCRYPT (a TrueCrypt-compatible) <device> and sets up a
          mapping <name>.

          <options> can be [--key-file, --tcrypt-hidden,  --tcrypt-system,
          --readonly, --test-passphrase].
```